# Tweepy - Twitter API 1.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I wrote a program back in API v 1.0 that crawls up tweets using urls, which worked perfectly.
Its core part goes like this:

```
import tweepy
auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('something','something')
auth1.set_access_token('something','something')
api=tweepy.API(auth1)

url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=" + tid
tweet = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

After 1.1 got released, I've changed the url from 1 to 1.1 and tried getting new OAuth,
but it gives me Bad Authentication, code: 215 error.

This may have been asked before, but I cannot find relevant information.
What exactly do I need to change from the code above?
Please help me out and I will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: what endpoint do you want to use? seems it's a depricated or moved one. with tweepy, it is strange to see urls hardcoding, api has more than enough functionality itself.

Comment: I'm trying to crawl up the conversation by checking in_reply_to_ID field repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I found, it is [`statuses/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid) endpoint you're trying to access.

You don't need to hardcode a link and authentication, it is all already done in tweepy. Simply make sure to use its latest version (with 1.1 bindings), and you'll get access to this endpoint with [`get_status`](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#API.get_status) method:

```
api = tweepy.api(auth)
tweet = api.get_status(id=tweet_id)
```

Note that this tweet will be a tweepy [tweet model](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/getting_started.html#models) object, and you can access it's fields as

```
ir2id = tweet.in_reply_to_status_id
```

Comment: thank you very much! btw, it says there is no attribute screen_name but in your link it still seems to have screen_name.. Has the name changed?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc `screen_name` is a user attribute, not a tweet

Comment: then it wouldn't be possible to obtain some kind of user identity from the tweet metadata?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc sure yes, `tweet.user.screen_name`. Refer to json structure (you can find a sample in endpoint description in Twitter API docs, see link in answer) for other fields.